# How can I distinguish separator and data the same in the CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Some of the data in the CSV file below has a semicolon inside. In the separator of this csv file, again semicolon, therefore data parse error.

```
Column1;Column2;Column3;Column4
abcd;e;1234;1;345;Nan
Michel;1234;1;345;234
Larin;3456;234;2;3466
```

As you can see in rows 1 and 3, there are many semicolons in column_1 and column_3. When I parse the data by semicolon, I get the following error.

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 840516, saw 5

Comment: Simply put you cannot, what you need to do is manually edit the file or use regex to remove the `;` inside words

Comment: How would one determine into which column the extra data go?

Comment: The last line in your example can be interpreted in multiple ways. I'd have some words with the person who generated said file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to determine which semicolons are separators and which ones are inside data,

You can escape semicolons inside data when exporting csv.

```
E.g. abcd\;e;1234;1\;345;Nan
```

Then, use escapechar parameter `escapechar = '\\'` when importing in pandas using `pd.read_csv`,

```
data = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', delimiter = ';', escapechar = '\\', header = 0)
```

Result:

```
  Column1  Column2 Column3 Column4
0  abcd;e     1234   1;345     Nan
```

Comment: Backslash is rather unconventional here; the standard CSV mechanism is to quote any field which contains the separator character literally.